# Angular 12 RxJs BehaviourSubject and HTTP Get request issue

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I’m new to RxJs and having issues getting a response back from a HTTP request when using a BehaviourSubject in my app. What is the correct approach to doing this?
By using chrome dev tools Ive noticed that the function is not even doing the network call. Before I tried using the BehaviourSubject I just used a simple Observable and the http request worked. I also noticed just sending some static data back rather then doing a http request then the subject works.

```
//Service

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Pokemon } from '../_model/pokemon';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PokemonService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  private pokemonListSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  pokemonList$: Observable<Pokemon> = this.pokemonListSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPokemonList2(){
    //This request works
    //this.pokemonListSubject.next('this is a pokemon') 

   this.http.get<Pokemon>(this.baseUrl + `pokemon/ditto`)
    .pipe(
      tap(value => {
        this.pokemonListSubject.next(value)
      })
    )
  }

}
```

```
//component

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Gen } from 'src/app/_model/gen';
import { Pokemon } from 'src/app/_model/pokemon';
import { GensService } from 'src/app/_services/gens.service';
import { PokemonService } from 'src/app/_services/pokemon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-screen',
  templateUrl: './screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./screen.component.css']

})
export class ScreenComponent implements OnInit {


  gens$: Observable<Gen[]>;
  pokemon2$?: any;

  constructor(public pokemonService: PokemonService, private genService: GensService) {
    this.gens$ = this.genService.getGens();

    this.pokemonService.pokemonList$.subscribe(pokemonList => this.pokemon2$ = pokemonList)
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  getPokemonByGen2(gen: Gen){
    this.pokemonService.getPokemonList2();
  }
}
```

```
//html

<div id="screen">

  <div class="pokedex">

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let gen of (gens$ | async)"> <a (click)="getPokemonByGen2(gen)">{{gen.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ng-container *ngIf="pokemon2$" >
    {{pokemon2$.name}}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: you ae not subscribing to the observable use a subscribe method

Comment: You neither return nor subscribe to the observable, so it's never actually triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use your method like given below,

```
  getPokemonList2(): void {
    //This request works
    //this.pokemonListSubject.next('this is a pokemon') 

   this.http.get<Pokemon>(this.baseUrl + `pokemon/ditto`)
    .subscribe(val => {
       this.pokemonList$.next(val);
     });
  }
```

Comment: that worked, thank you! why do you need to subscribe here? Does this subscription close automatically once the http request is complete?

Comment: it needs to be closed it doesn't do it automatically. If that was helpful please accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have **any** logic in your constructor, that's what `ngOnInit` is for. For any logic initialization, and listening to changes, in this case, your subject, `ngOnInit` is the right place to handle that.

Now, in your click event, you are calling your service, but, no one is subscribing to that HTTP call. You are only subscribing to your subject.

What is missing in your code is this:

```js
getPokemonByGen2(gen: Gen){
  this.pokemonService.getPokemonList2().subscribe();
}
```

Also, you are subscribing to your own special observable, aka `pokemonList$`
which is fine, but you are not handling the subscription. You need to store that subscription so you can "destroy" it if you navigate somewhere else, otherwise, you are creating a memory leak on your app.

```js
....
....
mySubscription!: Subscription;

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.mySubscription = this.pokemonService.pokemonList$
     .subscribe(pokemonList => this.pokemon2$ = pokemonList);
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.mySubscription?.unsubscribe();
}

getPokemonByGen2(gen: Gen){
  this.pokemonService.getPokemonList2().subscribe();
}
```

Now if you don't want to handle the subscription, instead of subscribing into your `pokemonList$`, you could pipe it and store it in your local property as:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.pokemon2$ = this.pokemonService.pokemonList$
     .pipe(
       map((pokemonList) => pokemonList)
     );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. Adding the subscribe to this.pokemonService.getPokemonList2().subscribe(); doesn't work. it gives an error of Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: @PhilipB Add a return to your getPokemonList2() function returning the whole thing, return this.http.get ....

Comment: that worked. So if I use the subscribe here I can use the pipe the pokemonList$ and I dont have to deal with unsubscribing?

Comment: Yeah, you should delete the .subscribe inside your service function, usually, you don't subscribe inside your service logic, leave it as you had it adding the return keyword. Then, just pipe your own subject and see if it works. Let me know

Comment: no luck changing the subscribe to pipe unfortunately. It works if I leave it as subscribe though.

Comment: Sorry the pipe did work when accessing it with the async pipe in the template.